# JSON can't get Int value from php

Tags: php, android, json

My problem is simple. I can't get the value of item from php and my android app crashes. My PHP:

```
<?php
$control["value"] = 0;
echo json_encode($control);
?>
```

My Java Android:

```
private static final String CONTROL_URL = "xxxxx.controller.php";
int control;
```

...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    //it crash here
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(CONTROL_URL);

    try {
          control = json.getInt(CONTROL_URL);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (control == 0) {
                   //Do something...
            }
```

When i tried to go to my php file on browser it shows me:   {"value":0} . So could someone help me solve this problem? By the way, my url - xxxxx.controller.php isn't real, I use a real one for my app, but I don't want to show it.

Comment: running n/w related operation on the ui thread i am guessing. post stacktrace and `getJSONFromUrl` method

Comment: shouldn't it be `control = json.getInt("value");`?

Comment: It didn't changed anything, my app still crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error log shows that you are making a network call on the main thread (NetworkOnMainThreadException), which android prohibits. You will have to move the call for getting the JSON to a separate thread. Using an Async Task will accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks! I solve this problem, but I didn't use Async Task. I had a check if user have Internet accesses and i moved it before my JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't json.getInt require "value" as the parameter not the URL?
so json.getInt("value")

Comment: I changed it, but my app still crash. It crash on   JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(CONTROL_URL);

Answer (score 1):

When you're grabbing the integer from your `JSONObject`, the key you inputted is the url which doesn't make sense. Try changing it to

```
control = json.getInt("value");
```

Comment: It didn't changed anything, my app still crashes

Comment: I uploaded my errors here: http://tinypic.com/r/2myrq84/5 Do you need another part of my errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$control = array('value' => 0);
echo json_encode($control);
?>
```

Comment: It didn't changed anything, my app still crashes