# Android JSON crashes NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, json

I have my project, everything is great, but there is one problem. I gave my app to friend, to test it. Then she said that it crashes. We found out that app crashes here:

```
            isInternetPresent = cd
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            if (isInternetPresent) {

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject json = jParser
                        .getJSONFromUrl(CONTROL_URL);

                try {
                    control = json.getInt("value");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch
                    // block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (control == 1) {
                        new AttemptLogin().execute();

                } else {
                    //I'm showing something when there is not allow to use it
                }
            } else {
                //I'm showing something when there is no Internet connection
            }
```

And my class for sending values to database:

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(file_url);
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position += 1;
            String pos = position.toString();

            int success;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pos", pos));

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(VOTE_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Dalyvis.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Siunčiame balsą...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

    }
```

I don't know why, but for emulator everything was great. I really know that my friend have internet connection. Could anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

I guess exception is a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Because later, I had first getting control value and then checking if device has internet connection. I replaced it. Then at first was check for internet connection and then for control value. For emulator everything was okay. Check my previous question and the right answer: [JSON can't get Int value from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054682/json-cant-get-int-value-from-php)

In fact my app crashes here:

```
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(CONTROL_URL);

                    try {
                        control = json.getInt("value");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: do you have a LogCat for the crash?

Comment: No, because for emulator and my phone is everything okay and I don't have another android phone

Comment: do you at least know what the exception was that caused the crash?

Comment: No, but I guess it is a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Because later, I had first getting control value and then checking if device has internet connection. I replaced it. Then at first was check for internet connection and then for control value. For emulator everything was okay. Check my previous question and the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054682/json-cant-get-int-value-from-php